# How to launch external URLs with Ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some external urls. I need to display those in the ionic app, currently I am using `iframe` for that, it is working fine.

But some of my URL contain video files, when I call that URL it is crashing in android version.

Comment: you can use a Cordova plugin. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/ , iframes should not be used, they cause many memory issues too.

Comment: HI thanks for your help. i tried the framework but still have the same problem

Comment: Please post code sample?

Comment: $scope.iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
                        document.getElementById("myFrame").src = value['url'];  this code using in js file  and  <body>
  <iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" height={{iframeHeight}}>
</iframe>
</body> this one in html page

Comment: Here is a great code sample, follow this guide, works like a charm
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: Thanks a lot.it is working but i need t auto play my video file how can i do that?

Comment: You are playing the video by online streaming or from local file @Testuser

Comment: I am now using local file and i can use the video file from my server also